# Deleting missing data with CountryData

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to delete all of the missing entries after executing this line:

```
data = {CountryData[#, "PopulationGrowth"], CountryData[#, "LifeExpectancy"]} & /@ CountryData[];
```

Comment: [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html)

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 8):

```
data = {CountryData[#, "PopulationGrowth"], CountryData[#, "LifeExpectancy"]} & /@ CountryData[];

data2 = Select[data, FreeQ[#, _Missing] &];
data3 = DeleteCases[data, _?(! FreeQ[#, _Missing] &)];
data4 = Pick[data, FreeQ[#, _Missing] & /@ data];
data5  = (data /. {_Missing, _} | {_, _Missing} :> Sequence[]);
data6 = Cases[data, Except[{_Missing, _} | {_, _Missing}]];

Length /@ {data, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6}
(* {240, 228, 228, 228, 228, 228} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

[`DeleteMissing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteMissing.html?q=DeleteMissing) is the built-in function for this task:

```
DeleteMissing[data, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

I am adding this one for its novelty, but I would not use it in production as it is to uncontrolled:

```
Block[{Missing},
  Missing /: {_Missing, _} := Sequence[];
  Missing /: {_, _Missing} := Sequence[];
  data
] // Length
(* 228 *)
```

But, it operates by rewriting the behavior of `Missing` when it is found in a `List`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cases[data, _?(VectorQ[#, QuantityQ] &)] // Length
(*  228  *)
```

Caveat/limitation: The data, except for the `Missing` items, need to be quantities.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to some of the [answers by kguler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65925/18476), but using [`BlankSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankSequence.html?q=BlankSequence)

```
data7 = data /. {___, _Missing, ___} :> Sequence[];
data8 = DeleteCases[data, {___, _Missing, ___}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply:

```
DeleteCases[data,Missing[_],Infinity]
```

or, to delete the whole entry, if any part is missing:

```
DeleteCases[data,{Missing[_],_}|{_,Missing[_]},Infinity]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest fastest way is:

`DeleteCases[data, Missing[_]]`

data can be a list of data or a function returning a list of data.