# Delete nested lists with Missing["NotAvailable"]

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data

I have a list of stock symbols and related information containing some entries `Missing["NotAvailable"]`. I would like to delete all nested lists which contain a NotAvaiable entry, as *Mathematica* obviously does not support these instruments anymore (see also http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FinancialData.html).

The list entries are formated as follows:

```
indexMaster= {"^RDM-SO", Missing["NotAvailable"], "AMEX"}
```

I tried to use the following function, but it does not work.

```
instruments =
 DeleteCases[indexMaster, {p__, q_String, r__} /;
    StringMatchQ[q, "*NotAvailable*"] -> {p, q, r}]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to delete the `Missing["NotAvailable"]` entries?

Thanks

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [Deleting missing data with CountryData](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65923/125)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
indexMaster= {"^RDM-SO", Missing["NotAvailable"], "AMEX"}
Select[indexMaster, Internal`LiterallyAbsentQ[#, "NotAvailable"] &]
(* {"^RDM-SO", "AMEX"} *)

indexMaster2 = {"^RDM-SO", Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing[], "AMEX", "NotAvailable"};
Select[indexMaster2, Internal`LiterallyAbsentQ[#, "NotAvailable"] &]
(* {"^RDM-SO", Missing[], "AMEX"} *)

DeleteCases[indexMaster2, _?(Internal`LiterallyOccurringQ[#, "NotAvailable"] &)]
(* {"^RDM-SO", Missing[], "AMEX"} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Missing["NotAvailable"]` is not a string. Its `Head` is `Missing`, therefore you can use

```
instruments = DeleteCases[indexMaster, _Missing]
```

> ```
> {"^RDM-SO", "AMEX"}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same pattern as what you don't want to see:

```
DeleteCases[indexMaster,Missing["NotAvailable"]]
(* {"^RDM-SO", "AMEX"} *)
```