# Removing Missing["NotAvailable"] data in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I created a list using [`IsotopeData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IsotopeData.html) command. There are some elements in the list which are `Missing["NotAvailable"]`. I want to have the only available data in the list.  Here is my code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
IsotopeData[{94, 236}, "DecayEnergies"]
```

which gives me

```
{Quantity[5867.07, "Kiloelectronvolts"], Missing["NotAvailable"], 
Missing["NotAvailable"], Quantity[-1588.01, "Kiloelectronvolts"]}
```

But in fact I want to have a list like:

```
{Quantity[5867.07, "Kiloelectronvolts"], Quantity[-1588.01, "Kiloelectronvolts"]}
```

How can I figure it out?

Comment: `DeleteMissing`?

Comment: See also: [(1235)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1235/121)

Comment: What's the fun in finding duplicates? :)  OK, a better match would have been [Deleting missing data with CountryData](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65923/10397)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data

```
list = IsotopeData[{94, 236}, "DecayEnergies"]
```

There are many ways

```
list /. Missing[_] -> Nothing (* Replace all instances of a pattern       *)

DeleteMissing[list]           (* A specialized function just for that     *)

Cases[list, _Quantity]        (* Get Cases with the correct Head          *)

DeleteCases[list, _Missing]   (* Delete cases with the wrong Head         *)

Select[list, Not@*MissingQ]   (* Select cases for which MissingQ if False *)
```

all give

> ```
> {Quantity[5867.07, "Kiloelectronvolts"], 
>  Quantity[-1588.01, "Kiloelectronvolts"]}
> ```

The way to figure it out should have been to read the documentation for [`Missing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: There's `MissingQ`, too, but I don't know how it differs from `_Missing`. It may be as simple as `MissingQ[_Missing] := True; MissingQ[_] := False`, but I honestly don't know.